# url.routerurl web api link for jquery ajax call

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, url-routing

I'm trying to create a link to my `WebApi` controller using `Url.RouterUrl`, but I don't know how to add the controller action to it, this is what I have in my view:

```
var url = '@Url.RouteUrl("DefaultApi", new { httproute = "", controller = "ClientApi"})';
```

I want to add the `FindClients` action to the `Url.RouterUrl`, I have trying adding `action=FindClients`, but it produced this url `/api/ClientApi?action=FindClients`, I need my url to be `/api/ClientApi/FindClients`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following key to `App_Start\WebApiConfig.cs`

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "Extended",
    routeTemplate: "api/{namespace}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { }
);
```

As default route do not have `{action}`

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{namespace}/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

Then use

```
 @Url.RouteUrl("Extended", new { httproute = "", controller = "ClientApi"})
```